# Rails ActiveJob SQS and record still not exists when executing the Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, rails-activejob

I am using SQS as a backend for my ActiveJobs.

I have a very simple job that is sent to the queue in a `after_create` callback of my Model:

```
after_create :update_stuff_after_create
```

This initializes an ActiveJob:

```
UpdateStuffAfterCreateJob.perform_later(self.id)
```

The job is sent to the SQS queue properly. The problem is that when **the other instance** who is in charge of reading from the queue tries to execute the job I see an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`:

```
class UpdateStuffAfterCreateJob < ActiveJob::Base
  def perform(id)
    publisher_offer_click = MyModel.find(id) # ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    my_model.update_stuff
  end
end
```

Looks like the record exists in the instance that send the Job but the record doesn't exist in the instance that is consuming the Job.

[image]

---

I have been debugging deeper and I have create this Job:

```
class TestingEntityExistsJob < ActiveJob::Base
  def perform(id, exists_outside, time_outside_string)
    Rails.logger.info "[TestingEntityExistsJob] #{id}, #{MyModel.last.id}, #{Time.now.strftime("%H:%M:%S.%L")}, #{time_outside_string}, exists: #{MyModel.where(:id => publisher_offer_click_id).exists?}, exists_outside: #{exists_outside}"
  end
end
```

And I call it like this in the `after_create` of my Model:

```
TestingEntityExistsJob.perform_later(self.id, MyModel.where(:id => self.id).exists?, Time.now.strftime('%H:%M:%S.%L'))
```

I have weird results like these:

```
[2017-05-05 16:13:12.773] [TestingEntityExistsJob] 30645284, 30645284, 16:13:12.781, 16:13:12.720, exists: true, exists_outside: true
[2017-05-05 16:13:12.773] [TestingEntityExistsJob] 30645281, 30645284, 16:13:12.781, 16:13:12.659, exists: true, exists_outside: true
[2017-05-05 16:13:12.913] [TestingEntityExistsJob] 30645283, 30645284, 16:13:12.929, 16:13:12.838, exists: true, exists_outside: true
[2017-05-05 16:13:12.964] [TestingEntityExistsJob] 30645285, 30645285, 16:13:12.970, 16:13:12.927, exists: true, exists_outside: true
[2017-05-05 16:13:13.368] [TestingEntityExistsJob] 30645286, 30645285, 16:13:13.391, 16:13:13.309, exists: false, exists_outside: true
[2017-05-05 16:13:13.374] [TestingEntityExistsJob] 30645287, 30645285, 16:13:13.391, 16:13:13.339, exists: false, exists_outside: true
[2017-05-05 16:13:13.447] [TestingEntityExistsJob] 30645288, 30645288, 16:13:13.453, 16:13:13.411, exists: true, exists_outside: true
[2017-05-05 16:13:13.718] [TestingEntityExistsJob] 30645289, 30645289, 16:13:13.723, 16:13:13.658, exists: true, exists_outside: true
[2017-05-05 16:13:14.702] [TestingEntityExistsJob] 30645290, 30645290, 16:13:14.722, 16:13:14.642, exists: true, exists_outside: true
[2017-05-05 16:13:14.842] [TestingEntityExistsJob] 30645291, 30645291, 16:13:14.850, 16:13:14.789, exists: true, exists_outside: true
[2017-05-05 16:13:17.658] [TestingEntityExistsJob] 30645292, 30645292, 16:13:17.663, 16:13:17.599, exists: true, exists_outside: true
[2017-05-05 16:13:18.558] [TestingEntityExistsJob] 30645294, 30645294, 16:13:18.565, 16:13:18.513, exists: true, exists_outside: true
[2017-05-05 16:13:18.648] [TestingEntityExistsJob] 30645293, 30645294, 16:13:18.652, 16:13:18.592, exists: false, exists_outside: true
[2017-05-05 16:13:19.565] [TestingEntityExistsJob] 30645295, 30645295, 16:13:19.570, 16:13:19.514, exists: true, exists_outside: true
[2017-05-05 16:13:21.899] [TestingEntityExistsJob] 30645296, 30645295, 16:13:21.918, 16:13:21.771, exists: false, exists_outside: true
[2017-05-05 16:13:21.916] [TestingEntityExistsJob] 30645297, 30645295, 16:13:21.923, 16:13:21.832, exists: false, exists_outside: true
[2017-05-05 16:13:22.541] [TestingEntityExistsJob] 30645298, 30645298, 16:13:22.547, 16:13:22.484, exists: true, exists_outside: true
[2017-05-05 16:13:23.223] [TestingEntityExistsJob] 30645299, 30645299, 16:13:23.228, 16:13:23.171, exists: true, exists_outside: true
```

You can see the record always `exists` from outside but not always inside of the Job execution. Some times the `MyModel.last.id` is smaller than the `id` of the record I am trying to load.

Any suggestion of why this can be happening? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My actual workaround is `UpdateStuffAfterCreateJob.set(:wait => 2.seconds).perform_later(self.id)` what I considered ugly and it should not be necessary :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is that `after_create` fires just as the transaction of the `save` is being committed. This causes there to be a brief period during which the job's database connection doesn't have access to the record as the model's database connection hasn't committed it yet.

You'll want to use

```
after_commit :some_method, on: [:create]
```

instead of

```
after_create :some_method
```

https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods/after_commit